# Unable to use ADALiOS Library to implement single sign-on with Azure Mobile Apps?

Tags: ios, adal, azure-mobile-services

In the Azure Mobile Apps client for iOS (https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-apps-ios-client), the MSClient class provides a method

```
-(void)loginWithProvider:(nonnull NSString *)provider
               token:(nonnull NSDictionary *)token
          completion:(nullable MSClientLoginBlock)completion;
```

I am trying to use this method with a token retrieved from the ADALiOS.  I am following this tutorial (https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-ios-aad-sso/).  This tutorial is before the November update to Mobile Apps

Is it possible to use AD single sign on with Azure Mobile Apps?

Answer (score 0):

With the help of azure-mobile-app team I was able to track down the issue.  The problem was due to a mismatch audience in the authentication token.  See https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-apps-ios-client/issues/14 for more details.